# Should all members shared between WebSocket sessions be synchronized?

Tags: java, session, websocket, synchronization

In my WebSocket application I have Sets containing data that I share between sessions - each session can access all the data in the set. I do this by simply making the Sets static.

My understanding from reading around the web is that WebSockets (in my case running on Tomcat 8) follow the Single Thread Model, in that there is an individual thread for each session. So...

My question is; **should I make the shared members synchronized, as they can be accessed by any WebSocket thread?**

Or does WebSockets take care of this for me?

I'm assuming that I should synchronize everything shared, but just confirming! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have **multiple threads** reading from a **shared** Set (or any non thread safe variable) that may be written(updated) at the same time then you **need to synchronize** them. Java 8 adds a new `synchronizedSet` method to `Collections` (see Collections.synchronizedSet). Prior to Java 8 you provide your own synchronization. More on creating a Java 8 `synchronizedSet` can be found in this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet-java.util.Set-).

Even with Websockets the synchronization is needed because you have defined static data (a `Set`) that can be accessed by multiple `websocket` sessions simultaneously. Instance data (non-static variables) do not need synchronization because the single thread model guarantees that no two methods on your class (in the same session) can execute simultaneously. Information on the one thread per Websocket session can be found in this [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm). Specifically it says:

> As opposed to servlets, WebSocket endpoints are instantiated multiple times. The container creates one instance of an endpoint for each connection to its deployment URI. **Each instance** is **associated with one and only one connection**. This behavior facilitates keeping user state for each connection and simplifies development because **only one thread is executing the code of an endpoint instance** at any given time.

So per instance variables (non-static) need no special synchronization. Websockets guarantees thread safety in the Single Thread Model. However this doesn't apply to shared data (static variables) between those instances. Because they can potentially operate in their own threads you need to provide synchronization where appropriate.